# What happened to Eli and Oskar in Let the right one in?

Tags: plot-explanation, let-the-right-one-in

What happened to Eli and Oskar? Someone says that in the book they mix blood, and Oskar becomes a vampire. Can anyone confirm this? & also was Eli a boy or a girl?

Comment: Eli is girl and it's crystal clear in the film too.

Comment: Eli is a girl, "girl." If I remember correctly the name was pronounced like "Ally" in the film.

Comment: i think Oskar is the new Håkan. Oskar will grow old and help Eli with her need for blood and Oskar will age just like Håkan did ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oskar does not become a vampire in the book. It is Håkan who becomes a vampire in the book. Also in the book, it is disclosed that Eli is a boy who was castrated years ago when he was converted to a vampire.

In the movie, neither Håkan becomes a vampire nor is Eli disclosed to be a boy. Oskar and Eli flee. And as atm mentions in the comment, Oskar will grow old just like Håkan.